# What's the name of exception for app pool recycle?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to do some custom processing when method fails on app pool recycle, app domain recycle, or IIS shutdown. Is there a specific exception type? maybe: ApplicationException? instead of using generic `Catch (exception ex)`

Comment: You mean you won to capture the recycle of the pool, or capture the errors ?

Comment: @Aristos, What I need to do is to run a custom stored procedure right before IIS recycles. I thought to do it in Catch block, but if there are better solutions, that would be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right before IIS recycle point is the `Application_End` at global.asax

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know if it is possible to catch during the time my method run. I have a variable in the method. so if apppool recycles during method execution I want to write that variable to a database.

Comment: From the moment you enter here, you can call a static function on your method and make anything, or wait for a signal that you have set, or signaling the method to make something, the pools wait until this function ends - or until the timeout occurs. The time out is a pool parameter that you can change.